# How to show answers of a flashcard type programmed iPhone app between two arrays, xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, storyboard

- I'm trying to display questions in a viewcontroller using storyboards
  and when the user clicks  show answer.  It brings it from view
  controller to another. The other view controller just shows the
  answer and has a back button.
- Both viewcontrollers use the same
  class.  The user can toggle next and previous from one string to
  another in the app from the question.
- When I click show answer on first question, I
  can see the first string in the answers array which says lol but when I go the next
  question and I click show answer it says the same the answer.
- I linked the ib action showanswer but it did does not seem to have any 
  effect. The Show Answer button goes to the other view controller
  through a segue and also has the ib action show answer linked to it.

So my question is what am I doing wrong in the ib action showAnswer? If I am approaching this flashcard type application wrong, what am I doing wrong?

```
//
//  BiologyViewController.m
//  Biology
//
//  Created by Jacob Brans on 6/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Jacob Brans. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BiologyViewController.h"

@interface BiologyViewController ()

@end

@implementation BiologyViewController
@synthesize labelsText;
@synthesize textView, textViewanswer1;



-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:// Time Together
              @"What is Biology?",@"What is yo mamma?",nil];
    step= 0;
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    answers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:// Time Together
              @"lol",@"wow",nil];
    textViewanswer1.text = [answers objectAtIndex:step];



    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];

}


-(IBAction)showanswer:(id)sender{
    textViewanswer1.text = [answers objectAtIndex:step];

}

-(IBAction) nextclicked:(id)sender{
    // titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"iology is the scientific study of life. Bam",@"This works? Wow",@"lol", nil];
    if (step<titles.count-1) {
        step++;
    }
    else
    {
        step= 0;
    }
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}





-(IBAction) prevClicked:(id)sender{
    //  titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Biology is the scientific study of life. Bam",@"This works? Wow",@"Still Works.",@"garret is the coolest awesome person awesome wowowowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", nil];
    if (step>0) {
        step--;
    }
    else
    {
        step =titles.count-1;
    }
    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}


-(IBAction) randomClicked:(id)sender{

    step = 1+arc4random() %(titles.count);


    textView.text = [titles objectAtIndex:step];
    labelsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", step+1, titles.count];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: what is `step` (property,static variable)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something similar in a prototype I wrote last week. It was a quick and dirty prototype so I actually hard coded some of this stuff. I can share it with you so you can see an example. My segue code looks like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DessertsCategory"]) {
        CategoryViewController *cvc = (CategoryViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [cvc setCategoryname:@"Desserts"];
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"KidsCraftCategory"]){
        CategoryViewController *cvc = (CategoryViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [cvc setCategoryname:@"Kids Crafts"];
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PartyCategory"]){
        CategoryViewController *cvc = (CategoryViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [cvc setCategoryname:@"Party"];
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TrendingCategory"]){
        CategoryViewController *cvc = (CategoryViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [cvc setCategoryname:@"Trending"];
    }
}
```

Basic stuff, look for the segue's identifier (I have a segue for each button), get the destination controller and call that setCategoryname method on it (note, that's a pretty bad name for a method. If you use properties and have a string named Categoryname the property will generate a SetCategoryname method for you when synthesize gets called. So you'll want to give that a better name like "SetValueOfCategoryName" or "UpdateCategoryNameString", whatever you want just avoid set+propertyName).

Anyway, on my CategoryViewController that method looks like this:

```
-(void)setCategoryname:(NSString *)categoryName {
    self.categoryName = categoryName;

}
```

Easy, you could probably just call the category name accessor instead of creating a method there. In hindsight not sure why I did it that way, other than I probably wrote it at 3am, but it works so I'll give it to you exactly as I have it. Then on my CategoryViewController my viewWillAppear method looks like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.lblDiscover.text = self.categoryName;
}
```

lblDiscover is one of my labels so I just set that value before it appears. You could do it in the viewDidAppear method if you wanted too, but there might be a little flicker as the text changes:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.lblDiscover.text = self.categoryName;
}
```

Hope that helps some. I wrote the previous answer when I was working in Windows so I had to recall it all by memory, thought it should still work though.

Comment: I will definitely try it tonight Jake, thank you for your help. I tried your earlier answer and your way seems to be good, I just can't seem to get that first way to work. I'm going to try your new way later on. Thanks again.

Comment: Jake so this code all goes in the initial view controller class? Or do I need a second class?

Comment: I went ahead and took your answer Jake as the answer but I just decided to avoid the segue and just have two buttons one shows the answer and one shows the question on the same screen and same class. Took little coding at all haha. Thanks for all the support!

Comment: This is using two classes. If you use the flip animation it would look like the card is flipping over. The first block of code would be on your question view controller and the rest of the code would be on your answer controller. Other than the viewWillAppear method and a method to close the viewcontroller the answer controller would be complete. It's a nice mechanism for easily opening and closing an answer with a flip. Two buttons work though too, with just changing the text. Glad you found something that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, When you pushed your view to show the ans. The Variable step set to zero. so you need to make step as property. Or make Step as class Variable (static).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think your issue is that you have a button that calls a segue and calls code. You should only do one or the other. So you'll want to remove that ibaction for show answer and use something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WhateverMySegueIsNamed"]) {
        MyViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.textViewanswer1.text = [answers objectAtIndex:step];
    } 
}
```

What I typically do for something like that is instead of setting the text on a label on a view controller that isn't the one I'm working on I'll pass the text as a property and do it on viewWillAppear instead. Something like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WhateverMySegueIsNamed"]) {
            MyViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
            controller.AnswerString = [answers objectAtIndex:step];
        } 
    }
```

then on the view will appear I'd have something like

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.lblAnswer.text = self.AnswerString;
```

It's also important if you're using properties to use the "self" keyword, I've had instances (in other languages as well) where I thought I was setting a property on the object I was working on but it was actually setting a value on another object or creating a new object all together and setting that value. Hope that helps!

Comment: Did you give your segue an identifier? If you click on the segue and then go to the Attributes Inspector (fourth icon on the top of your right bar) there's a text box there called "Identifier". You need to give it a name there and then replace the "WhateverMySegueIsNamed" string with that identifier. I'm still not sure if that text box will set that way since it's a UI element. To be safe I'd create the property for that string and do the view will appear method. That'st he safest way to do it.